# Adding Firebase Admin to Java Application

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-admin

I am trying to add Firebase admin to my java web application for controlling the CRUD operations in Firebase But it is throwing below error -

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

As I have seen the Firebase site, It should support jdk/jre 1.7 or higher and I am using 1.7. Still it is showing compatiblity issue.

```
 public void init() throws FileNotFoundException{
     FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
      .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("serviceFirebase.json").getPath()))
      .setDatabaseUrl("https://<MyAppName>.firebaseio.com/")
      .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. The problem was with the firebase-admin jar. I was using version 4.0.0 which has some errors. As soon as I updated to version 4.0.2, the problem disappeared. :)

Comment: Has some errors, or is compiled using Java8 (which is what the error was telling you)?